# How does this for in Loop Work to Sort Numbers using Quick Sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

How does the `for in` loop work below to correctly sort the numbers in the `left` array and `right` array for the quick sort implementation below?

I'd like an example of a first example iteration of the `sortArr(left)` recursive call, then another iteration, and so on (maybe up to three or four iterations).

Then I'll be able to understand the `sortArr(left)`, including the `sortArr(right)` recursive call.

```js
const unsortedArr = [31, 27, 28, 42, 13, 8, 11, 30, 17, 41, 15, 43, 1, 36, 9, 16, 20, 35, 48, 37, 7, 26, 34, 21, 22, 6, 29, 32, 49, 10, 12, 19, 24, 38, 5, 14, 44, 40, 3, 50, 46, 25, 18, 33, 47, 4, 45, 39, 23, 2];

let sortArr = (arr) => {
  
 if (arr.length < 2) return arr;

  const pivot = arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];

  let left = [];
  let equal = [];
  let right = [];
  
  equal.push(pivot);
  
  for (let element of arr) {
    if (element < pivot) {
      left.push(element); 
    } else if (element > pivot) { 
      right.push(element);
    } 
 }
  
  
 let sortedArr = sortArr(left)
     .concat(equal)
     .concat(sortArr(right));
  
  return sortedArr;
  
};

console.log(sortArr(unsortedArr));
```

Comment: There is no `for ... in` loop though

Comment: Also, this is a good *conceptual* demonstration of how a Quicksort works, but in practice you'd never write it this way. The whole point of Quicksort is to save space, and making lots of new arrays in the process of sorting is the wrong way to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, 'for in' is not equivalent to 'for of'. Why dont you just create new array with let's say names of animals and try to use it in loop: for (let animal of ['zebra', 'jerboa', 'honeybadger']) and console.log(animal)?

Comment: Actually it *doesn't* work correctly, there's an `else` case missing that pushes the `element` into `equal` if it's neither smaller nor larger than the pivot element.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at using while loops instead:  
https://codepen.io/hollyw00d/pen/abdObPE